# Create Extjs 4 grid actioncolumn with text?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

how to create ExtJs 4 grid action column with text?
this is my code

```
{
    xtype : 'actioncolumn',
    text : lang('publish'),
    width    : 100,
    tdCls: 'x-publish-cell',
    items : [{
         getClass : function(v, meta, rec) {
             if (rec.get('isPublished') == true) {
                 //this.items[0].tooltip = 'Test';
                 return 'y';
             } else {
                 return 'n';
             }
         }
     }
```

How to create ExtJs 4 grid action column with text?

Comment: You want it to be text with no image, or with an image?

Comment: text with an image. like [the image][the text here]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the column's [`renderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer). The trick is that Ext specifically hide a CSS rule to hide content of action columns:

```
.x-grid-cell-inner-action-col {
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

So you will have to compensate for that.

Example:

```
{
    xtype:'actioncolumn',
    renderer: function() {
        return 
            '<div style="float:right; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1em;">'
                + 'Hey!' 
            + '</div>'
    },
    items: [
        // ...
    ]
}
```

Here I've used inline style, but a custom CSS class would probably be better.

Now that allows you to add some text to the column. If what you want to achieve is to add some text *per action item* in the column, you'll have to override [`Ext.grid.column.Action#defaultRenderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-method-defaultRenderer).